# The MADDPG action prints a specific value

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
    p = p_func(p_input, int(act_pdtype_n[p_index].param_shape()[0]), scope="p_func", num_units=num_units)
    p_func_vars = U.scope_vars(U.absolute_scope_name("p_func"))

    # wrap parameters in distribution
    act_pd = act_pdtype_n[p_index].pdfromflat(p)

    act_sample = act_pd.sample()
```

How do I get the concrete value of act_simple